# Guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
# API controller for authentication
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Api::V1::ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
    unless @user && @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
      @error_message = 'Invalid username or password'
      render 'shared/error', status: :unauthorized
    end
  end
end
```

I use Rubocop to check my code if it matches to Ruby guidelines. I got the following error:

```
Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression.
    unless @user && @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
```

So, I don't understand how I can make this code better using guard clause. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 39):

Following rubocops spec : https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/GuardClause

Something like...

```
return if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
@error_message = 'Invalid username or password'
render 'shared/error', status: :unauthorized
```

Comment: Not good. If user && user.authenticate I need to render view by default

Comment: what osman did above is equivalent to your code.  it will still render the create template when user authenticates successfully.

Comment: Link is invalid

Comment: @NikitaFedyashev the above RuboCop spec link is working fine.

Answer (score 7):

There is a handy rule in programming, the name is "eager return" so in this case what this `Guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression` alert means is that One should be probably using an eager `return` statement instead of wrapping code inside an `if` statement (block of code inside an `if` or any other conditional)

So it is better to declare this:

```
  def method_name
    return unless something?
    # some code logic here
  end
```

Than this...

```
def method_name
  if something?
    # some code logic here
  end
end
```

In coding we are always looking for simplicity and atomic definitions and eager `return` statements are a really nice way to tight up the code.

Comment: Thank you. A really helpful explanation that enabled me to solve my problem!